# Xamarin Forms iOS .Net Standard 2.0 SOAP WSDL - MonoTouch does not support dynamic proxy code generation

Tags: wcf, soap, xamarin.ios, mono, wsdl

I have a Xamarin Forms App. Using latest Xamarin/VS2017 I'm using the built in Connected Service to generate my Proxy from WSDL.

[image]

It generates a file which I can reference in my .Net Standard project. It compiles/builds fine in all projects. Runs and works fine in UWP.

In iOS I receive the following error when using the service:

```
monotouch does not support dynamic proxy code generation override this method or its caller
```

**Is this not the correct way to generate a WCF Proxy from a WSDL in Visual Studio for Xamarin iOS? Is there a different way I should be generating?**

I've also tried `svcutil` which produces the same results.

```
svcutil https://MyApp/services/Service?wsdl /namespace:*,MyAppServices
```

I've seen some chatter around `slsvcutil` Is this correct you need to use Silverlight command line? I don't have Silverlight installed at this point either.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53856/problems-to-start-slsvcutil-exe

Comment: Have you read [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15148/how-to-access-wcf-service-in-ios-platform-using-xamarin)?

Comment: Yes - I'm just trying to confirm I need Silverlight installed to generate a valid Proxy Class for WCF/Xamarin

Comment: I'm running in to the same issue with our development, we've used WCF plenty of times before using .NET standard projects and have got them working, but for some reason on the recent release we're having issues all over the place. Did you find a suitable solution to this?

Comment: I had to download silver light and run slsvcutil which generated a proxy class I was able to use

Comment: Just doesn’t seem the best way to get it done

Comment: @aherrick do you know if this is still an issue in 2020? I am running into exact problem and I land here. about to install SilverLight, I still have not been able to find any help so far. Thanks!